# adding setTimeout to close a preloader

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not so good at javascript and I'm trying to add setTimeout to close my preloader after a certain time, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thank you so much.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var e = document.readyState;
    "interactive" == e
        ? ((document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"), (document.getElementById("contents").style.visibility = "hidden"))
        : "complete" == e &&
          setTimeout(function () {
              document.getElementById("interactive"), (document.body.style.overflow = "auto"), (document.getElementById("load").style.visibility = "hidden"), (document.getElementById("contents").style.visibility = "visible");
              
          },
           1e3);
           setTimeout(e, 3500);
};
```

Comment: What is the expected result? And what is happening instead?

Comment: preloader is closing after page load and not after 3500, I would like to make it close after 3500. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve , this is what you are looking for.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => { // wait to load the page
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('.loader').style.display = 'none' // hide the loader after 3.5 seconds
    console.log('loaded')
  }, 3500)
})
```

```html
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```